# Recycler View shows the list of item but does not scroll and neither the items are clickable

Tags: android, layout, android-recyclerview, scrollview

The app consists of two recycler views each having its own layout XML files. When the data is provided to the adapter associated with the recycler view, it renders the items but then the view is not scrollable and neither the items in the view are clickable.

Fragment class

```
public class OrderListFragment extends Fragment {

private RecyclerView orderListRecyclerView;
private TextView orderListEmptyTextView;
private RecyclerView.Adapter adapter;

protected OrderList orderList;

@Override
public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    if (getArguments() != null) {
        orderList = (OrderList) 
         getArguments().getSerializable(ORDER_LIST_SERIALIZED);
    }
}

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup 
container,
                         @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_order_list, container, false);
}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle 
savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    initializeViews(view);
    initAdapter();
}

private void initializeViews(View view) {
    orderListRecyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.order_list_recycler_view);
    orderListRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    orderListRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new 
     LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
    orderListEmptyTextView = view.findViewById(R.id.order_list_text_view);
    if (orderList != null) {
        orderListRecyclerView.setVisibility(VISIBLE);
        orderListEmptyTextView.setVisibility(GONE);
    }
}

private void initAdapter() {
    if (orderList != null) {
        adapter = new OrderListAdapter(getActivity(), 
        orderList.getOrderDetails(), ORDER_LIST_FLAG);
        orderListRecyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
        }
    }
}
```

Its layout xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/order_list_recycler_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:visibility="gone"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/order_list_text_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:text="@string/no_order" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Can you guys have a look and suggest what should be done to get this working?

**EDIT**

OrderListAdapter

```
    public class OrderListAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<OrderListAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    private Context context;
    private List<Order> orderList;
    private String orderFlag;

    public OrderListAdapter(Context context, List<Order> orderList, String orderFlag) {
        this.context = context;
        this.orderList = orderList;
        this.orderFlag = orderFlag;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public OrderListAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.orderlist_row, parent, false);
        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull OrderListAdapter.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        final Order order = orderList.get(position);
        if (order != null) {
            if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(order.getName())) {
                holder.getOrderName().setText(order.getName());
            }

            if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(order.getStatus())) {
                holder.getOrderStatus().setText(order.getStatus());
            }

            if (orderFlag.equals(ORDER_LIST_FLAG)) {
                holder.getViewOrder().setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                holder.getViewOrder().setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        new AlertDialogFragment().createSingleChoiceDialog(context,
                                context.getString(R.string.order_detail),
                                order.getName(),
                                R.string.yes_button, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {

                                    }
                                }).show();
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return orderList.size();
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        private TextView orderName;
        private TextView orderStatus;
        private TextView viewOrder;

        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            orderName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_order_name);
            orderStatus = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_order_status);
            viewOrder = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_view_order);
        }

        public TextView getOrderName() {
            return orderName;
        }

        public TextView getOrderStatus() {
            return orderStatus;
        }

        public TextView getViewOrder() {
            return viewOrder;
        }
    }
}
```

Item_row.XML

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:elevation="3dp"
        tools:targetApi="lollipop">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tv_order_name"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:padding="5dp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    tools:text="Name of order" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tv_order_status"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:padding="5dp"
                    tools:text="Order Status" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_margin="5dp">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tv_view_order"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:padding="5dp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:text="@string/view"
                    android:visibility="gone"
                    android:textColor="@color/text_view_button"/>
            </LinearLayout>

        </RelativeLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Post your `OrderListAdapter` and the item xml layout too.

Comment: That's because your recycler view has a height of wrap_content. It will render it beyond your screen. Try bounding it to like match_parent.

Comment: @tompee Thanks buddy!! I tried initially it was match_parent but it did not work, some posts in stack suggested to make it as wrap_content so I tried that too but still did not work.

Comment: Also if I want to use the same layout for two fragments but change the data that is fed to adapter on runtime can that work I mean is it advised and allowed in Android.

Comment: Yup that is perfectly fine. Adapters convert your data to a form acknowledged by the view. It doesn't matter if your data is static or dynamic.

Comment: what's your recyclerview version on build.gradle file?

Comment: @masoudvali I have not explictly imported recycler view however imported implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'

Comment: try this  : 
       rcv_list.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false); after rcv.setAdapter